# How to fix this error net::ERR_ABORTED 404?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes when I load my website, it generates this error on the console:

GET https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-5756325242704349.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404          adsbygoogle.js:1

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? When this happens, the site does not stop loading, which makes it slow.

Comment: adsbygoogle.js how did you add this script in your file, can you show ?

Comment: <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
      google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5756325242704349",
      enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
   });
</script>

Comment: you should try this `<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-5756325242704349" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
`

Comment: did you tried in head tag?

Comment: even so when updating the pages sometimes the error appears, because the home page is never the same it always changes the ads and the content ...

Comment: you should put https:// here `<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> <script> $(document).ready(function () { (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({ google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5756325242704349", enable_page_level_ads: true }); }); </script>`

Comment: I think it already worked.
Anyway if I see that it continues to appear, I will contact you again ...
Thanks!!